# Make whole row clickable in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactJs. I want to make the whole row clickable.

```
deleteApp(appId) {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure want to delete this app?")) {
      this.props.deleteApp(appId)
    }
  }

  showAds(appId) {
    console.log("Clicked")
  }
```

This is the function I'm trying to trigger the `onClick` event. For now I'm just consoling anything inside the function but it doesn't console anything

```
<tbody>
  {
    apps.map(function (app, index) {
      return <tr key={index} onClick={() => { showAds(app._id) }}>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          {app.app_name}
        </td>
        <td>
          <a onClick={() => { deleteApp(app._id) }}>
            Delete
            </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    })
  }
</tbody>
```

Above is the code which I'm using to perform the `onClick` event, but this doesn't work. I did the same with delete button and it works fine. But when I try to make the whole row clickable I cannot trigger the onClick event. I have searched many places but couldn't find any suitable solution to this problem.

The last thing i tried was to make the

Am I doing something wrong here?

**UPDATE**

[Full code](https://github.com/krushnaj/onClick)

Comment: hi, I think problem is the function of user that creates the table row is not bound to your react component. The value of this will not be your react component and handleClick will not exist as a property of this

Comment: Try <tr key={index} onClick={() => { alert(app._id) }}>  and see if this works. Check if you showAds is valid/ passed properly. else post full code

Comment: so what exactly do I do so that the onClick works perfectly @dev

Comment: @AnilKumar  <tr key={index} onClick={() => { alert(app._id) }}> this works perfectly. Yes the showAds is passed properly and it is valid also

Comment: hi, either use this. showAds or do const showAds = this.showAds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use this.showAds or do const showAds = this.showAds

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that I didn't initialize the `this.showAds` inside the `render` function.

```
 render() {
const { user } = this.props.auth
const { apps } = this.props.apps
const deleteApp = this.deleteApp
```

> const showAds = this.showAds

I just had to declare the `showAds` inside the `render` function and it started to respond.